# Will my app get rejected because of this?

Tags: iphone, ipad, appstore-approval

i am developing a ebook reader app for iPad and i am facing a issue related to the design aspects of the bookshelf. I am posting a sample photo of my bookshelf here. I want the book shelf to have a horizontal navigation similar to that of the iBooks. Will this come under violation of  Apple's HIG?? Will they consider this design to be a imitation of their iBooks design and reject it?? I'm worried...

[image]

Comment: Please consider joining [the App Store proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30702/app-stores) on Area 51.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly they are not consistent about rejection. Good news they are more keen on their logos and device picture, so you can't use an iPhone/iPod in your app as picture for explain controls but sometimes you see apps like this. I am not developer myself but friends of mine and blogs about the topic says this. Thats why I didn't pay $99 for being a developer.

Your app resemble to Apple's app but in real life book shelves are resemble to each other, so we can call them the same. Bad thing: only by submitting it you will know they approve it or not...

Important thing, to kill all bug before this. If they approve it with the bug (that can happen), and then you want to update it, maybe they reject the updated version.